# Cyrillic in redis

Tags: go, redis, decode, cyrillic, redis-cli

Using redis-cli, I add data in Cyrillic to the redis queue, if using redis-cli to get the queue data, we will see `"\xaf\xe0\xae\xa1\xa0"`.

In GO

```golang
msg, _ := redis.String(R.conn.Do("LPOP", key))
```

result

[image]

How can I get the Cyrillic alphabet?
I tried it

```golang
encoder := charmap.MacintoshCyrillic.NewDecoder() // Windows1251 to
s, _ := encoder.String(msg)
fmt.Print(s)
```

it didn't work

Comment: It looks like you are using the Redigo client.  Redigo does not transform or convert bytes sent to or from the Redis server.

Comment: The `"\xaf\xe0\xae\xa1\xa0"` string corresponds to russian word _проба_ (test, sample) in `cp866` encoding. Tried in python using  `b"\xaf\xe0\xae\xa1\xa0".decode('cp866')`.

Comment: @JosefZ thank

```go
encoder := charmap.CodePage866.NewDecoder()
s, _ := encoder.String(msg)
```

it works

Comment: @JosefZ How do you know it's Russian, the same word can be Serbian, Belarusian, Ukrainian... 

Comment: @Z.Kosanovic  It **is** Russian however I don't assert an _exclusive_ claim to… For instance, Google translate _detects_ `проба` as Bulgarian… Sorry…

Answer (score 0):

When you see garbage symbols like that, the issue is very often that data (text) encoded with one format is being decoded as something else.

I use chardetect (python) to figure out what the input data is encoded as:

```
echo -e "\xaf\xe0\xae\xa1\xa0" | tee /tmp/j | chardetect 
<stdin>: IBM866 with confidence 0.99
```

uchardet works too:

```
$ uchardet /tmp/j
IBM866
```

To display the word correctly:

```
$ echo -e "\xaf\xe0\xae\xa1\xa0" | iconv -f IBM866 -t UTF-8
проба
```

- https://github.com/chardet/chardet
- https://pypi.org/project/chardet/

Similar projects:

- https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/uchardet/
- http://jchardet.sourceforge.net/
- https://github.com/jmhodges/rchardet